# Xamarin.Forms: App runs in simulator and on device, however it freezes at splash screen on iOS device only when trying to debug

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Xamarin.Forms: My app runs in simulator and on iOS devices that I'm testing on, however it freezes at splash screen on iOS device only when trying to debug.

From the device log I've come across several errors. I don't know what these mean. How can I go about troubleshooting this?

```
Error (261) / TUE.iOS(CoreTelephony): Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13, descriptor: <private>

Error (52) / SpringBoard(SplashBoard): [com.TUE] Failed to generate image for <XBApplicationSnapshot: 0x149439e10; \M-b\M^@\M-&BD9861B846DA>

Error (62) / assertiond: [TUE.iOS:286] SyscallError: setpriority(PRIO_DARWIN_ROLE, 286, 3): No such process
```

Any suggestions as to what might be going on?

Edit:  Also, my project settings have "Enabled Debugging" set to true on port 10000. I've tried other ports with no luck.

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Hi ,where modified compared to the last successful building ? And need to get more error info to check . By the way ,having a check whehter miss some permission for iOS , they will not crash in simulator however in physical device .

Comment: I believe my development profile contains all the necessary permissions. Besides, it runs on the physical devices. The only thing that doesn't work is debugging on the physical device.

Comment: OK , if you can share a sample project here , I will check in my local site . You also can have a check with the last successful building compare to the current version .

Comment: I am working through differences with the last working version. I believe that there is a package incompatibility issue.

Comment: That's possible , need to find out which package results in .However ,according to error log can not clearly know where problem is . If using version control , can check where modifies affect this .

Comment: I'm not using version control yet: I don't know how to use git yet. I used to use SVN but don't have an SVN server that's being backed up. Luckily, I always keep an older working version. Over the past 2 days I gradually upgraded the old working version to parity with the newer non-working version, upgrading package at a time and saving "checkpoints" along the way in case I needed to fall back. I never found what is causing the issue. I have 2 projects virtually identical. One debugs fine the other one hangs whenever the App class is instantiated from the iOS Delegate class.

Comment: After syncing the packages between the two I literally copied over every single file from the non-working project to the working project except for the 2 VS Project files (netstandard project/iOS project), and so now I'm 100% certain that all the code is identical but the 2 files. The only other difference would be the packages folder at the solution level. However, the project in question still hangs when trying to instantiate the App singleton.  I could just move on but I really need to figure out what's wrong because this happened to me about a year ago using VS for Mac.

Comment: Ok , if related to nuget package , you can reisntall them in another project . And clean bin  folder to clean project to rebuild it to check whehter it works.